# Can I get an identity of an F# quotation?

Tags: f#, quotations

F# quotation is a wonderful feature, it allows us to treat F# expression as normal F# value. In my context, I use F# quotation to code Gpu kernel, and compile it into Gpu bitcode module.

There is one problem. I don't want to compile Gpu kernel each time, I would like to cache the compiled Gpu bitcode module. Thus I need a key, or identity from an F# quotation value. I would like to have a cache system like:

```
let compile : Expr -> GpuModule

let cache = ConcurrentDictionary<Key, GpuModule>()

let jitCompile (expr:Expr) =
    let key = getQuotationKey(expr)
    cache.GetOrAdd(key, fun key -> compile expr)
```

There is one solution, to use the quotation expr instance as the key. But look at this piece of code:

```
open Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations

let foo (expr:Expr) =
    printfn "%O" expr

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 

    for i = 1 to 10 do
        foo <@ fun x y -> x + y @>

    0
```

If I check the compiled IL code, I got these IL instructions:

```
IL_0000: nop
IL_0001: ldc.i4.1
IL_0002: stloc.0
IL_0003: br IL_00a2
// loop start (head: IL_00a2)
    IL_0008: ldtoken '<StartupCode$ConsoleApplication2>.$Program'
    IL_000d: call class [mscorlib]System.Type [mscorlib]System.Type::GetTypeFromHandle(valuetype [mscorlib]System.RuntimeTypeHandle)
    IL_0012: ldc.i4.5
    IL_0013: newarr [mscorlib]System.Type
    IL_0018: dup
    IL_0019: ldc.i4.0
    IL_001a: ldtoken [mscorlib]System.Int32
    IL_001f: call class [mscorlib]System.Type [mscorlib]System.Type::GetTypeFromHandle(valuetype [mscorlib]System.RuntimeTypeHandle)
    IL_0024: stelem.any [mscorlib]System.Type
    IL_0029: dup
    IL_002a: ldc.i4.1
    IL_002b: ldtoken [FSharp.Core]Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Operators
    IL_0030: call class [mscorlib]System.Type [mscorlib]System.Type::GetTypeFromHandle(valuetype [mscorlib]System.RuntimeTypeHandle)
    IL_0035: stelem.any [mscorlib]System.Type
    IL_003a: dup
    IL_003b: ldc.i4.2
    IL_003c: ldtoken [mscorlib]System.Tuple`2
    IL_0041: call class [mscorlib]System.Type [mscorlib]System.Type::GetTypeFromHandle(valuetype [mscorlib]System.RuntimeTypeHandle)
    IL_0046: stelem.any [mscorlib]System.Type
    IL_004b: dup
    IL_004c: ldc.i4.3
    IL_004d: ldtoken [mscorlib]System.String
    IL_0052: call class [mscorlib]System.Type [mscorlib]System.Type::GetTypeFromHandle(valuetype [mscorlib]System.RuntimeTypeHandle)
    IL_0057: stelem.any [mscorlib]System.Type
    IL_005c: dup
    IL_005d: ldc.i4.4
    IL_005e: ldtoken [mscorlib]System.Tuple`5
    IL_0063: call class [mscorlib]System.Type [mscorlib]System.Type::GetTypeFromHandle(valuetype [mscorlib]System.RuntimeTypeHandle)
    IL_0068: stelem.any [mscorlib]System.Type
    IL_006d: ldc.i4.0
    IL_006e: newarr [mscorlib]System.Type
    IL_0073: ldc.i4.0
    IL_0074: newarr [FSharp.Core]Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations.FSharpExpr
    IL_0079: ldc.i4 372
    IL_007e: newarr [mscorlib]System.Byte
    IL_0083: dup
    IL_0084: ldtoken field valuetype '<PrivateImplementationDetails$ConsoleApplication2>'/T1805_372Bytes@ Program::field1806@
    IL_0089: call void [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers::InitializeArray(class [mscorlib]System.Array, valuetype [mscorlib]System.RuntimeFieldHandle)
    IL_008e: call class [FSharp.Core]Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations.FSharpExpr [FSharp.Core]Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations.FSharpExpr::Deserialize40(class [mscorlib]System.Type, class [mscorlib]System.Type[], class [mscorlib]System.Type[], class [FSharp.Core]Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations.FSharpExpr[], uint8[])
    IL_0093: call class [FSharp.Core]Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations.FSharpExpr`1<!!0> [FSharp.Core]Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations.FSharpExpr::Cast<class [FSharp.Core]Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc`2<int32, class [FSharp.Core]Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc`2<int32, int32>>>(class [FSharp.Core]Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations.FSharpExpr)
    IL_0098: call void Program::foo(class [FSharp.Core]Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations.FSharpExpr)
    IL_009d: nop
    IL_009e: ldloc.0
    IL_009f: ldc.i4.1
    IL_00a0: add
    IL_00a1: stloc.0

    IL_00a2: ldloc.0
    IL_00a3: ldc.i4.s 11
    IL_00a5: blt IL_0008
// end loop

IL_00aa: ldc.i4.0
IL_00ab: ret
```

This is a large code, but basically it does these things in the loop:

- Load byte array for the quotation from some static field
- Setup type informations
- Call `FSharp.Quotations.FSharpExpr::Deserialize40` to re-create the quotation object;

So from this observation, my questions are:

1. Although quotation are stored in one static field, but each time we write `<@ ... @>`, they will create a new `Expr` instance, even when the static field is same. So I cannot use the `Expr` instance as the key, it would be good to get the static field token and use that as the key. But I don't know how to get that information;
2. We saw there are lots of IL instructions to just re-create an quotation instance, even when they are the same quotation. This might have some performance issues, can F# compiler be optimized here?

Regards,
Xiang.

@kvb gave a wonderful answer. Looks like we just need to fix the `Var` compare in the quotations (when var has a counterpart and has the same type). Follow his answer I made the following tests and it works:

```
let comparer =
    let rec compareQuots vs = function
        | ShapeLambda(v,e), ShapeLambda(v',e') ->
            compareQuots (vs |> Map.add v v') (e,e')
        | ShapeCombination(o,es), ShapeCombination(o',es') ->
            o = o' && (es.Length = es'.Length) && List.forall2 (fun q1 q2 -> compareQuots vs (q1, q2)) es es'
        | ShapeVar v, ShapeVar v' when Map.tryFind v vs = Some v' && v.Type = v'.Type ->
            true
        | _ -> false

    let rec hashQuot n vs = function
        | ShapeLambda(v,e) ->
            hashQuot (n+1) (vs |> Map.add v n) e
        | ShapeCombination(o,es) ->
            es |> List.fold (fun h e -> 31 * h + hashQuot n vs e) (o.GetHashCode())
        | ExprShape.ShapeVar v ->
            Map.find v vs

    { new System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer<_> with 
        member __.Equals(q1,q2) = compareQuots Map.empty (q1,q2)
        member __.GetHashCode q = hashQuot 0 Map.empty q }

type Module = int

let mutable counter = 0

let compile (expr:Expr) =
    counter <- counter + 1
    printfn "Compiling #.%d module..." counter
    counter

let cache = ConcurrentDictionary<Expr, Module>(comparer)

let jitCompile (expr:Expr) =
    cache.GetOrAdd(expr, compile)

[<Test>]
let testJITCompile() =
    Assert.AreEqual(1, jitCompile <@ fun x y -> x + y @>)
    Assert.AreEqual(1, jitCompile <@ fun x y -> x + y @>)
    Assert.AreEqual(1, jitCompile <@ fun a b -> a + b @>)
    Assert.AreEqual(2, jitCompile <@ fun a b -> a + b + 1 @>)

    let combineExpr (expr:Expr<int -> int -> int>) =
        <@ fun (a:int) (b:int) -> ((%expr) a b) + 1 @> 

    // although (combineExpr <@ (+) @>) = <@ fun a b -> a + b + 1 @>
    // but they are treated as different expr.
    Assert.AreEqual(3, jitCompile (combineExpr <@ (+) @>))
    Assert.AreEqual(3, jitCompile (combineExpr <@ (+) @>))
    Assert.AreEqual(4, jitCompile (combineExpr <@ (-) @>))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating a new object each time through the loop doesn't necessarily mean that the object can't be used as a key, as long as the objects compare equal each time.

The real issue you'll have is that "the same" quotation means something different to you than to the F# compiler, particularly when it comes to variables in quotations.  For example, you can verify that

```
<@ [1 + 1] @> = <@ [1 + 1] @>
```

evaluates to `true`, and

```
<@ fun x -> x @> = <@ fun y -> y @>
```

evaluates to `false` (which hopefully makes sense, since the lambdas are equivalent up to renaming, but not identical).  Perhaps more surprisingly, you'll see that

```
<@ fun x -> x @> = <@ fun x -> x @>
```

also evaluates to `false`.  This is because the variables in each quotation are treated as different variables which just happen to share the same name.  You'll see the same behavior in your loop - each iteration's variable `x` is considered different.

However, all is not lost; all you need to do is to use a custom `IEqualityComparer<Quotations.Expr>`.  I think something like this should work to identify any quotations that are identical modulo variable renaming:

```
let comparer = 
    let rec compareQuots vs = function
    | Quotations.ExprShape.ShapeLambda(v,e), Quotations.ExprShape.ShapeLambda(v',e') ->
        compareQuots (vs |> Map.add v v') (e,e')
    | Quotations.ExprShape.ShapeCombination(o,es), Quotations.ExprShape.ShapeCombination(o',es') ->
        o = o' && (es.Length = es'.Length) && List.forall2 (fun q1 q2 -> compareQuots vs (q1, q2)) es es'
    | Quotations.ExprShape.ShapeVar v, Quotations.ExprShape.ShapeVar v' when Map.tryFind v vs = Some v' && v.Type = v'.Type -> 
        true
    | _ -> false

    let rec hashQuot n vs = function
    | Quotations.ExprShape.ShapeLambda(v,e) -> 
        hashQuot (n+1) (vs |> Map.add v n) e
    | Quotations.ExprShape.ShapeCombination(o,es) -> 
        es |> List.fold (fun h e -> 31 * h + hashQuot n vs e) (o.GetHashCode())
    | Quotations.ExprShape.ShapeVar v -> 
        Map.find v vs

    { new System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer<_> with 
        member __.Equals(q1,q2) = compareQuots Map.empty (q1,q2)
        member __.GetHashCode q = hashQuot 0 Map.empty q }

let cache = ConcurrentDictionary<Expr, Module>(comparer)
```

Comment: This is very smart :) I test it now.

Comment: it is a wonderful solution, looks like what we need to do is just to fix the compare of `Var` type. I made some tests and updated them to the question. The tests passes, thanks!

Comment: Now the only issue is, constructing quotation objects uses a lot of IL code, even when they represent the same function. This will have slight performance issue (especially when we want to do Gpu acceleration). But I guess this should be some optimization in F# compiler.

Comment: This answers only part of 1. but does not touch question 2, that F# compiler generates lots of IL instructions to just re-create a quotation instance. It is a serious performance issue, which should be improved. Any ideas how?

Comment: @Daniel - I can't think of many situations where creating lots of quotations in a tight loop makes sense, so even if it could be significantly improved I doubt it would make a noticeable difference for most users.  As such, I would guess there are many more impactful ways to improve the compiler (but I'm happy to be convinced otherwise if you've got a compelling use case).

Comment: @Daniel - (and as I point out in my answer, it's not to "just re-create a quotation instance", since the semantics of the language require that the instances are structurally unequal).

Comment: @kvb Actually the purpose of this usage is, we have a function defined in F#, then we want to launch it in Gpu. In C#, we can use delegate to specify which function you want (and also the argument type are deduced, so type-safe), we want have this feature like in C#, quotation is a way to help us locate the method, also with type-safe.